# como usar um asset de um package em laravel sem copiar para a pasta public

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Criei um package laravel que já está funcionando, Porem sou barrado na hora de usar os `assets`.
Sem utilizar o comando

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

não consigo acesso ao `{{asset ('css/file.css')}}` no meu blade.
eu gostaria de saber se há alguma forma de mudar o caminho do asset em meu arquivo *ServiceProvider.php* como posso indicar o caminho do arquivo de rotas, o caminho da pasta de Views, o caminho de traduçoes, ou migrations utilizando os codigos abaixo:

```
$this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__.'/Routes/web.php');//Define o arquivo de rotas
$this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/Resources/views', 'NoMePaCoTe');//Define a pasta de uso ao usar return view('NoMePaCoTe:file') para exibir View
$this->loadMigrationsFrom(__DIR__.'/Database/migrations');//Pasta de migrations
$this->loadTranslationsFrom(__DIR__.'/Resources/lang', 'NoMePaCoTe');//Pasta de traduçoes
```

O que faço para fazer algo como :

```
$this->loadAssetsFrom('/resources/assets/');//definir subpasta dentro do package como pasta de asset
```

e assim poder usar os assets no blade `{{asset('css/file.css')}}` ou `{{asset('NoMePaCoTe::css/file.css')}}`
Alguma solução para meu problema ?

Comment: Acredito que não é possível, já que a unica pasta que o navegador deve acessar é a public por questões de segurança. Porém você pode utilizar o webpack pra gerar o arquivo minificado do css que ta no resource/assets e copiar para a pasta public. Na documentação você pdoe ver isso: [Compiling Assets (Mix)](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mix)

Comment: @JedsonMelo, eu tenho um sistema multi-tenancy. onde cada package, responde em um domínio diferente. como falei, os packages ja estão funcionando e respondendo bem cada um em um dominio. o que eu quero nada mais é que forçar cada package use seu proprio asset sem ter que fazer a publicação deles. pra mim ja é conveniente não compilar, publicar e compilar  pra mim já é dois trabalhos. a unica coisa que compartilho entre eles é uma extrutura blade, uma parte de um navbar e um footer. o resto tudo é diferente. compreende? não tem sentido ficar publicando tudo na pasta public.